# Using regex to detect words that might have an apostrophe, encoded in ASCII?

Tags: python, html, regex, text, ascii

Working in Python, I'm trying to create a function that takes in a stock ticker as a string and returns the company name using html data scraped from Yahoo! Finance. I've got it working for all companies except one that contains an apostrophe. I inspected the html code and found that the apostrophe is encoded as such - I'm pretty sure it's encoded in ASCII. Here's a modified version of the html code:

```
 html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html id="atomic" class="NoJs featurephone" lang="en-US"><head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"><script>window.performance && window.performance.mark && window.performance.mark(\'PageStart\');</script><meta charset="utf-8"/><title>Dick&#x27;s Inc (DKS) Company Profile &amp; Facts'
```

What I would want to return is "Dick's". What I'm getting back is just "Dick". I'm using the re module and re.search. Here's my code:

```
 company_name = (re.search(r'(?<=</script><meta charset="utf-8"/><title>)\w+', html).group(0))
```

I've tried to include the apostrophe to make sure it doesn't stop there, but since that's not part of the html code, it doesn't find it anywhere. Should I be using something other than re.search? I've looked into re.findall but that wouldn't be solving my problem of finding and including the "'" but presented as an apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you don't want `Dick's, Inc (DKS)` or something more? Just wonder if you're getting the full names as expected. To get `Dick's`, you'll need to unescape your HTML then change your regex. The new one will look for one or more word characters or apostrophes in sequence.

```py
import html

html_string = '<!DOCTYPE html><html id="atomic" class="NoJs featurephone" lang="en-US"><head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"><script>window.performance && window.performance.mark && window.performance.mark(\'PageStart\');</script><meta charset="utf-8"/><title>Dick&#x27;s Inc (DKS) Company Profile &amp; Facts'
html_string = html.unescape(html_string)
company_name = (re.search(r'(?<=</script><meta charset="utf-8"/><title>)[\w\']+', html_string).group(0))
```

Result:

```py
"Dick's"
```

Comment: Thank you! Not to be difficult, but is there a way to unescape using the re library? I should have specified, this is for a project in which we're limited in what we can use.